# Type of nonlinear 1D Heat Equation with Neumann bounary conditions, functional co-efficients and boundaries

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've a follow a question about the heat equation PDE.

The equation I have is more complicated with additional terms.

$$aF(u)\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-bH(u)\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$$

with

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=0} =\frac{c*(u(x=0,t)-20)}{H(u(x=0,t) )}  \quad (1)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=h} =\frac{-e*(u(x=h,t)-10)}{H(u(x=h,t))} \quad (2)$$

$$u(x,0)=20  \quad (3)$$

The terms F and H are functions of u. The terms a, b, c, e are constant coefficients.  Since I have introduced extra terms, I suppose this PDE is no longer classified as the heat/wave equation?
Could this be called a nonlinear form of the heat/wave type of PDE?
I have functional coefficients of u and the boundary conditions also includes a function of u. Is it possible to solve this equation analytically?

Do I need to check uniqueness of any numerical solution or are numerical solution uniquie by definition? Would the Finite Difference method be suitiable, or is finite element or volume more appropriate,

Comment: I've been alerted to some errors with the formulation. I've corrected the LATEX eqns here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/1d-heat-equation-for-conduction-with-convective-bounary-conditions